# Why do people talk (or communicate)?

Tags: social-psychology, communication, speech, speech-comprehension

I think that people talk for planning immediate benefits or planning future benefits. For example if someone wants to eat a fruit on a tree but he doesn't know how to get it so he asks someone to get it for him so he talks. So do you think that these are the correct reasons why people talk?

Comment: what kind of answer would satisfy the question "why"?  what would qualify as sufficient explanation?  would one have to be able to explain every single utterance in terms of this answer?  is this an evolutionary question?

Comment: @honi No, a sufficient explanation would include some very basic reasons

Comment: what does that mean?  you have to be much more clear.

Answer (score 1):

We evolved from animals which live in groups. Social animals such as chimpanzees (our closest relatives) communicate to one another to warn of danger, call for help, express emotions, etc. In a broader sense, there are advantages to living in groups: Mutual defense, stronger attacks on prey, ability to share resources...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolution_of_human_intelligence#Social_brain_hypothesis

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sociobiology

Answer (score 0):

From psycholinguistic point of view, communication helps to understand others behaviour better even in a non-verbal way, economic basis of communication is the fact that humans are wanting beings who need things from food to luxuries and therefore need to communicate, evolutionarily, I would suppose communication help to adapt more to our environment. Consider your own self when you are sick and need to talk to those around or a doctor, without communication, would that be possible? You may want more about the usefulness of communication, see a brief summary here http://geniuslight.blogspot.com.ng/2015/11/psycholinguistics.html